# Google Earth Engine loading 2 different Sentinel 2A images for the same area

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-2

I'm new in GEE. My study area is covered by 2 different Sentinel2A images.

I can load one image with this code in which basin is my study area covered by two different Sentinel images.

```
var ls2018 = ee.Image(ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
.filterBounds(basin)
.filterDate('2018-06-1', '2018-06-30')
.filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10))
.first());
```

I'd like to add both on my project and create mosaic with them.
Which codes I can use for this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites. We're a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.  Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean mosaic two granules on the same date?

Comment: Yes, I'd like to mosaic two granules on the same date

Answer (score 0):

Some considerations:

- It's redundant the use of `ee.Image()` and `.first()`, since the output of the second one is an `ee.Image` object.
- Check `.first()` description:

> Returns the first entry from a given collection.

This function returns the first image of your image collection, so can't be used for mosaicking purposes, since you need more than one image.

- There is a `mosaic()` function available, this is an image collection function, it won't work over an `ee.Image` object. So the code adapted is:

---

```
var ls2018 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR')
               .filterBounds(basin)
               .filterDate('2018-06-1', '2018-06-30')
               .filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10))
               .mosaic();
```

Although mosaic *Composites all the images in a collection, using the mask.*, not only one date. If the output considers other images that you don't want, refine `.filterDate()` range

Comment: What if I'd like to choose the specific ones from the list of images? I mean there are 9 images belong the 3 different granules and I'd like to load 3 of them which captured in different dates?

Comment: Get IDs and use [ee.Image](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apidocs/ee-image), like `ee.Image("COPERNICUS/S2_SR/20200413T143731_20200413T145116_T19JBF")`